# How do we get negative values in this graph?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

Why does the following function have negative values?
E.g for x = 0.8 the value of y is negative but neither `sin(0.8 * 6)` is negative nor the `3^(-x/3)`.

[image]

Comment: $\sin(6\cdot0.8)<0$ since $\pi<4.8<2\pi$.

Comment: For $x=0.8$ you have $\displaystyle 3^{-\frac{0.8}{3}}\sin(6\cdot{0.8})\approx -0.743$. Also, as $\forall x:\ 3^{-\frac{x}{3}}>0$ we can write that $y<0$ when $\sin(6x)<0$, i.e when $\pi+2\pi k<6x<2\pi+2\pi k$ for $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @CarstenS: `sin(6 * 0.8) = sin(4.8) = 0.08367784333` using google calculator

Comment: @Galc127:How are you getting the minus? Isn't `sin(6 * 0.8) = sin(4.8) = 0.08367784333`?

Comment: Are you thinking in degrees? Don't.

Comment: @CarstenS:Why not? If that is the flaw can you please help me understand the problem?

Comment: @Jim, you should use radians when evaluating trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be thinking of $\sin(4.8)$ as the sine of $4.8°$, where a full circle corresponds to $360°$. This is not how this function is defined in mathematics, and it is not what was meant in the graph. The usual definition is that we measure the angles in such a way that a full circle corresponds to $2\pi$, which is the length of the unit circle. (This is why this is called arc length.)

Comment: In fact almost all mathematical software assumes $\sin(x)$ is equal to the sine of an angle $x$ measured in radians. The main exception is that pocket calculators often have a "degrees" mode as well as a "radians" mode.